# How to remove .0 without messing with number 10

Tags: python, pandas

so it might looks silly but how would you accomplish this merge.
So as you guys can see I tried summing two strings, but it is failling for some reason at number `Weeks_between = 10`

The type will be different, it is not consistent. This was just sample of data. it is actually close to 1million rows.

data:

```
cw = pd.DataFrame({ "Weeks_between": [1.0 ,2.0 ,3.0 ,4.0 ,5.0 ,6.0 ,7.0 ,8.0 ,9.0 ,10.0 ,11.0 ,12.0 ] ,
                     "Type" : ["a" , "b" ,"c" , "b" ,"c", "b" ,"c", "b" ,"c", "b" ,"c", "b" ]  })
```

my code:

```
cw["Weeks_between"] = cw["Weeks_between"].round(0)
cw["key"] = cw["Weeks_between"].map(str) + cw["Type"]
cw["key"] = cw.key.str.replace('.0', '').astype(str)

cw[["Weeks_between","key"]]
>>>
Weeks_between   key
1              1a
2              2b 
3              3c
4              4b
5              5c
6              6b
7              7c
8              8b
9              9c
10             b      #   <-- THERE IS THE PROBLEM
11             11c
12             12b
```

Comment: ok, could u fix the dataframe. the type column does not have the same length as weeks_between

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It is updated now @sammywemmy

Comment: hmm no weird encoding in there, right?

Comment: Try `cw['key'] = pd.Series('%d%s' % (w,t) for (w,t) in zip(cw.Weeks_between, cw.Type))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one option: Use string replace with a regex that identifies the period punctuation and add the columns.

```
cw['key'] = cw.Weeks_between.astype(str).str.replace(r'\.0','') + 
cw.Type

cw
```

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear, the type will be different not consistent.  This was just sample of data. it is actually close to 1million rows